# Maven and webpack hotswapping and IntelliJ

Tags: javascript, java, eclipse, maven, intellij-idea

I have a webpack file, such as:

```
module.export = {
    entry: { ... },
    output: { ... },
    devtool: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'dev' ? 'source-map' : false,
    cache: !(process.env.NODE_ENV === 'dev'),
    module: { loaders: [{
        test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
        exclude: 'node_modules',
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        query: { presets: [ 'es2015', 'react' ] }
    }]}
}
```

and a maven pom file:

```
...
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.github.eirslett</groupId>
            <artifactId>frontend-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>install node and npm</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>install-node-and-npm</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <nodeVersion>v4.4.5</nodeVersion>
                        <npmVersion>3.9.2</npmVersion>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>npm install</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>npm</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <arguments>install</arguments>
                        <installDirectory>target</installDirectory>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>webpack build</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>webpack</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <environmentVariables>
                            <environment>${profile}</environment> <!-- dev -->
                        </environmentVariables>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
...
```

Current result of this is that I have to refresh the project every time I make a change in eclipse (in IntelliJ I can't even figure out how to refresh, I have no idea how to solve this neither) in order to see the changes made in babel (javascript). This triggers a new `webpack` build, which, as it's a big number of js files, can take 10-20 seconds. I don't know how I could run something similar to `webpack --watch` during development.

So my question goes 2 ways here.

1) How do I do the "refresh" functionality from eclipse in IntelliJ?

2) How do I hotswap the JS file and can I make it a bit faster during development?

Sorry if the info is unsufficient, any information, even another answer is more than welcome. I'd ask the question in more detail, but I'm not sure where to start. Thanks!